# Pushing the Android Studio code to Bitbucket without Cloning

Tags: android, git, android-studio, bitbucket

I have a project which was on my another laptop. The same android project is present in Bitbucket. I changed the laptop and imported the project in Android Studio and started working.

Now, I have changed the code in my local repo. As I did not connect the bitbucket with the Android studio, I did not push the code. Now I am trying to connect the project with Bitbucket but not sure how to do it.

Can someone please help me on how to push my code without cloning the project.

Thanks,
Arindam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git remote add origin <bitbucket_repo_url>
```

Now your local repo connected to the Bitbucket repo without clone the Bitbucket repo.

Comment: I did. But when I am trying to push, it is asking for Git User Name and PWD saying GIT username is not defined.